# Find inverse polynomial in python in GF2

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, polynomials, inverse

I'm fairly new to Python and I have a question related to the polynomials.
Lets have a  high-degree polynomial in `GF(2)`, for example :
`x^n + x^m + ... + 1`, where `n`, `m` could be up to 10000.
I need to find **inverse polynomial** to this one. What will be the fastest way to do that in Python (probably using `numpy`) ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure many people understand what you mean by GF(2). Clarify your question and give more detail about the mathematical background needed to understand your question.
Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: That's like asking whether a *car* will be the best transportation option. For many applications yes. But if you want to travel between Spain and Mexico a plane or boat might be necessary... You better first provide an algorithm. Numpy is good for doing things in *bulk*. Not for scalar mathematics.

Comment: I would suggest looking at CRC polynomials (Cyclic Redundancy Checks). Some libraries might support finding the inverse polynomial of a given CRC polynomial.

Comment: GF(2) is a finite field consisting of the set {0, 1}, with modulo 2 addition as the group operator and modulo 2 multiplication.For example:
x + 1, 
x^6 + 1, 
x, 
x^1000, 
1, 
...
Obviously, we could also have  polynomials
with negative coefficients. However, -1 is the same as +1 in GF(2).

Comment: @Ondrej Instead of a comment, that information should be added to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have basically **two** options:

- Use **sympy.polys.galoistools**, Sympy is an excellent python library for symbolic mathematics. However, at least in my experience, if the polynomial has a very high degree (which is common in error-correction coding theory) sympy is very slow.

  ```
  from sympy.polys.galoistools import gf_gcdex, gf_strip

  def gf_inv(a, irr_poly):  # irriducible polynomial 

      return gf_gcdex(gf_strip(a), irr_poly, 2 , ZZ)[0]
  ```

This solution is generical for all GF(2^p) fields e.g. GF(2)/(x^p+1).

- If your polynomial has a very high degree sympy is too slow and you have to develop your own Extended Euclidean Algorithm routine and all the other functions required to perform this algorithm.

Personally since i had to invert polynomial of in GF(2) of very high degree (in the ten-thousands !) too i have developed myself the EEA using numpy but only for GF2[x] polynomials:

```
def gf2_xgcd(b, a):
"""Perform Extended Euclidean Algorithm over GF2

Given polynomials ``b`` and ``a`` in ``GF(p)[x]``, computes polynomials
``s``, ``t`` and ``h``, such that ``h = gcd(f, g)`` and ``s*b + t*a = h``.
The typical application of EEA is solving polynomial diophantine equations and findining multiplicative inverse.


Parameters
----------
b : ndarray (uint8 or bool) or list
    b polynomial's coefficients.
a : ndarray (uint8 or bool) or list
    a polynomial's coefficients.
Returns
-------
y2 : ndarray of uint8
     s polynomial's coefficients.
x2 : ndarray of uint8
     t polynomial's coefficients.
b : ndarray of uint8
    h polynomial's coefficients.

Notes
-----
Rightmost element in the arrays is the leading coefficient of the polynomial.
In other words, the ordering for the coefficients of the polynomials is like the one used in MATLAB while
in Sympy, for example, the leftmost element is the leading coefficient.

Examples
========

>>> x = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], dtype="uint8")
>>> y = np.array([1, 0, 1], dtype="uint8")
>>> gf2_xgcd(x,y)
(array([0, 1, 1, 1], dtype=uint8),
 array([1, 1], dtype=uint8),
 array([1], dtype=uint8))

"""

x1 = np.array([1], dtype="uint8")
y0 = np.array([1], dtype="uint8")

x0 = np.array([], dtype="uint8")
y1 = np.array([], dtype="uint8")

while True:

    q, r = gf2_div(b, a)

    b = a

    if not r.any():
        break

    a = r

    if not (q.any() and x1.any()):  # if q is zero or x1 is zero
        x2 = x0
    elif not x0.any():  # if x0 is zero
        x2 = mul(x1, q)
    else:
        mulres = mul(x1, q)

        x2 = gf2_add(x0, mulres)

    if not (q.any() and y1.any()):
        y2 = y0
    elif not y0.any():
        y2 = mul(y1, q)
    else:
        mulres = mul(y1, q)

        y2 = gf2_add(y0, mulres)

    # update
    y0 = y1
    x0 = x1
    y1 = y2
    x1 = x2

return y2, x2, b
```

Of course to perform the EEA one needs firstly to define functions that allow to perform **addition**, **multiplication** and **division** on the GF2[x] field.

In fact i have developed a **python module** which is available in **GitHub**: [pyGF2](https://github.com/popcornell/pyGF2) which can efficiently compute polynomial arithmetic over GF2[x] including polynomial inversion orders of magnitude faster than Sympy.
The EEA code here is taken directly from that repo.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use numpy.polyval().

It evaluate a polynomial at specific values.

```
In [1]: p = np.poly1d([1, 1, -10])  # Use a poly1d to represent the polynomial.

In [2]: y = 100

In [3]: (p - y).roots
Out[4]: array([-11.,  10.])
```

Numpy is the library that you are searching

Comment: This is not what I want. This will simple find roots of given polynomial. I need to find **inverse polynomial** to given polynomial.
Anyway, thanks for answer

Answer (score -2):

Try to use mathematical package sage

Comment: please share an example code how you would solve this problem